# Conseguir valor entre llaves

Tags: python

Tengo una función para remplazar `{$}` de una string por el valor de algo lo que quiero que haga es elimine los `{}` y me devuelva `$` seguido de lo que tenga ejemplo: `{$numero}` quedaría `$numero` y luego devolvería la string que se le paso pero `{$numero}` remplazado por el valor de `$numero` (el valor de numero estaría en un diccionario) esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
Datos = {"$numero":15}
def Formatear_Datos(cadena:str) -> str:
    #Como hago para conseguir el valor entre las {}
```

Solo necesito saber como conseguir el valor ente las `{}` de lo demás me encargo (el uso de expresiones regulares esta permitido).

Comment: `str.replace('{', '').replace('}', '')` ??

Comment: @AlfaRojo No serviria porque aun asi tendria que dividir la string para acceder a $numero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esta expresión regular `\{(\$\w+)\}`.

La parte central `\$\w+` reconoce el simbolo "$" seguido de uno o más letras/digitos. Hay que usar `\$` para evitar interpretar `$` como fin-de-linea. Al poner el patrón entre paréntesis estas indicada "capturar" el texto reconocido.

Ahora, esto tiene que aparecer entre corchetes (`{}`), que son caracteres especiales en una expresión regular, por lo que también debo escaparlos anteponiendo "".

El reemplazo lo haremos usando simplemente `replace`. Los valores a reemplazar los guardamos en diccionario, indexado por "$nombre" y conteniendo el string de reemplazo.

**Demo**

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"\{(\$\w+)\}")

tests = [
    "numero: {$numero}",
    "varios {$valor1} y {$valor2}"
]

diccionario = {"$numero": "1", "$valor1": "10", "$valor2": "20"}
for test in tests:
    partes = patron.findall(test)
    for parte in partes:
        completo = "{" + parte + "}"
        test = test.replace(completo, diccionario[parte])
    print(test)
```

produce:

```
numero: 1
varios 10 y 20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: puede hacer el remplazo si hay mas de dos pares de llaves?

Comment: El código hará todos los reemplazos.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tu variable `Datos` es un diccionario de un elemento, desconocemos (Porque no lo has especificado en tu pregunta) si siempre será de un solo elemento o podría tener más. De cualquier forma, existen varios métodos para obtener `$numero` de `Datos`.

Un diccionario cuenta con dos partes, "llaves" y "valores", de la siguiente forma ([Documentación de diccionarios](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/))

```
Diccionario = {
    'llave1': 1,
    'llave2': 2
}
```

En tu caso `Datos` tiene únicamente una llave `$numero` y su valor es un entero `15`

Para acceder a la(s) llaves de un diccionario puedes hacerlo de las siguientes formas

### Opción 1

Iterando a través de tu diccionario utilizando el método `keys()`

```
Datos = {"$numero":15}

list1=[]
for e in Datos.keys():
  list1.append(e)
  
print(list1)
```

Salida

```
['$numero']
```

### Opción 2

Convertir a una lista utilizando la función `list()`

```
Datos = {"$numero":15}
list2 = list(Datos.keys())
print(list2)
```

Salida

```
['$numero']
```

### Opción 3

Desempaquetando con `*`

```
Datos = {"$numero":15}

list3 = [*Datos]

print(list3)
```

Salida

```
['$numero']
```

### Opción 4

Utilizando `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

Datos = {"$numero":15}

list4 = list(map(itemgetter(0), Datos.items()))

print(list4)
```

Salida

```
['$numero']
```

En todos los casos la forma de obtener directamente el texto sería a través de su índice, en este caso, todas las listas tienen un solo elemento y por lo tanto su índice sería `0` por lo que puedes utilizar (Esto aplica para las 4 opciones)

```
lista3[0]
```

Salida

```
$numero
```